# java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Integer; Concatenate/Merge/join two Integer[] Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, integer, wrapper

I'm trying to concatenate/merge two Integer[] array and store it in an other Integer[]. But I'm getting bellow error at run time.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Integer; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Integer; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at AllInOnePack.MainClass.AllInOne.main(AllInOne.java:61)`

My code is like this.

**Main class.java**

```
    static Integer[] hardCodeValus = {1,2,3,4};
    static Integer[] userValue = {1,2,3,4};
    concatArray = new Integer[hardCodeValus.length+userValue.length];
    concatArray = (Integer[]) StreamsFunc.concatenate(hardCodeValus, userValue);
```

**StreamsFunc.java**

```
    public static <T> Object[] concatenate(T[] hardCodeValus, T[] userValue) 
    {
            return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(hardCodeValus), Arrays.stream(userValue)).toArray();
    }
```

During run time I'm getting the error. Why this is not found in compile time then?

Comment: Casting happens during runtime and ClassCastException are always RuntimeExceptions. When you are casting you are basically telling your compiler "trust me bro, i know what kind of object this is better than you" so of course there will be no compile errors. Just like `final String string = (String) new Object();` will compile even though the cast makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this is not found in compile time then?

Because you *casted* the result of `concatenate` to `Integer[]`. Had you removed the cast, there will be a compiler error saying that `Object[]` (the return type of `concatenate`), cannot be converted to `Integer[]` (the type of `concatArray`).

Note that the parameterless [`Stream.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray()) returns an instance of `Object[]`, not an array of whatever type of element the stream contains. It can't possibly do the latter because of type erasure.

> **Returns:**
>
> an array, whose runtime component type is `Object`, containing the
> elements of this stream

Also note that it is unnecessary to initialise `concatArray` to `new Integer[...]`, if `concatenate` is going to return a new array *anyway*.

To fix `concatenate`, one way would be to call the [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) of `toArray` with an `IntFunction`:

```
public static <T> T[] concatenate(T[] hardCodeValus, T[] userValue, IntFunction<T[]> arrayCreator)
{
    return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(hardCodeValus), Arrays.stream(userValue))
            .toArray(arrayCreator);
}
```

Usage:

```
var concatArray = concatenate(hardCodeValus, userValue, Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

java.util.stream.Stream.toArray() returns an Array whose runtime component type is java.lang.Object.

But at compile time, as per method signature, you can return any subclass of Object which may or may not be assignable from java.lang.Integer type.

At compile time, code is syntactically correct as per method signature and data types in the main method.

Actual type check occurs at runtime at line concatArray = (Integer[]) StreamsFunc.concatenate(hardCodeValus, userValue);

So, you get an exception at Runtime rather than compile time because when concatenate method is executed it actually returns an Object array.